# Request undefined in Twilio using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, twilio

I created a webhook answering Twilio voice calls.

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var twilio = require('twilio');

router.post("/voice", (request, response) => {
  // var fs = require('fs');
  // var util = require('util');
  // fs.writeFileSync('./request.json', util.inspect(request.body), 'utf-8');
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log('Call received from ' + request.body.From);
  //twimlAnswer();}
```

The webhook and the connection work fine, but I am trying to access some of the request parameters usually provided by Twilio inside 'request' (similar way than this example https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/automated-survey-node-express#responding-to-a-phone-call)

I am getting the following log:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'From' of undefined
    at router.post
```

Do you know why I am not accessing request correctly? Most examples I found have no issue accessing request.body...

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using express body-parser??

Comment: @Molda yes I am, but I also deactivated it and doesn't make any difference at all, request.body is still undefined

Comment: @Molda, actually you put me in the right direction, I had declared body-parser but I never made the app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true })); That's why I couldn't notice any change and request was not being populated. Thanks!

Comment: @Jose Lopez.   What do you see when you do console.log(request)?   Does the request have any property that matches the payload sent by Twilio

Comment: @Naraen Thanks, I saw a lot of raw data in request before using body-parser. Once I used it I could reach all payload provided by Twilio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio sends webhook requests as URL encoded form parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request). So, to read the request body in Express you need to include the Body Parser module and set the app to use the `urlencoded` parser. A bit like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var twilio = require('twilio');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post("/voice", (request, response) => {
  console.log('Call received from ' + request.body.From);
  // respond to webhook
});
```

Comment: Thanks @philnash, indeed the issue was I wasn't using body-parser (the line 
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); was missing)